# NodeJs Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client When sending response from different function?

Tags: node.js, express

My router is calling a function which is calling another function but when I am sending response by using the other function I am getting error

> Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.

But the thing is I am only sending the response just once then how can I get this Error.

**App.js**

```
var Functions = require('./Functions');
app.post('/posts', Functions.fun1);
```

**Functions.js**

```
function func2(res, next) {
    res.json({status_code : 200, message : "Correctly Hit the URL!"});
    return next();
}

module.exports.func1 = function(req, res, next) {
    fun2(res, next);
}
```

**Edit** - Actually when I am sending the response directly(without using other function) then still it is showing same error, but the thing is when I don't send any response(E.g- remove res.send ) than I am not getting any response on the client side(E.g- But some response should come because as Headers are already sent ?)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `next` after `res.json` ,because you are finished processing the request.

```
function func2(res, next) {
   return res.json({status_code : 200, message : "Correctly Hit the 
                   URL!"});

}

module.exports.func1 = function(req, res, next) {
fun2(res, next);
}
```

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur if you don't use a fucntion inside an other function, it works ?

Comment: but I need to send response from a different function.

Comment: it's just to make sure if the problem is coming from using nested functions, if you use just one function does it work ?

Comment: Actually when I am sending the response directly then still it is showing same error, but the thing is when I don't send any response(E.g- remove res.send ) than I am not getting any response on the client side(E.g- But some resposne should come because as Headers are already sent ?)

Comment: I think the problem not coming from your handler, can you show all the code for `app.js` ?

Comment: it's difficult to locate the problem without the code :(

Comment: Got the solution, Actually, I was using for loop and inside that, I was sending response :(, Thanks anyway for helping :) (y)